# jQuery ui range slider gives wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI range slider for IE 9 and lower. With it I want to update the font size live.
My problem is that the range slider does not slide correctly. I cant get value 0 after 1. I also cant gate vaule 100 after 99.

```
function update() {
        var Rvalue = $('#range-slider').slider('value');
        $("#slidevalue").text(Rvalue);
    };
    $(function() {
        $( "#range-slider" ).slider({
            range:false,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            value: 20,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                update();
            }
        });
    });
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/f8h68gzj/)

Comment: Thanks [Arcans](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3137109/arcans) for organizing my codes and question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is your `update` function.
Try like this :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#range-slider" ).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 20,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slidevalue" ).text( ui.value );
        }
    });
});
```